# Spotfire: Calculated Column Percentile Column

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to calculate the Percentile/P90 for each row in my data table among all other rows that have the same value in two other columns for all entries that occurred before it.

I have tried the following:

```
P90([Value]) OVER (Intersect([Genre (Primary)],[Days To Release]))
```

And this:

```
Percentile([Value],90) OVER (Intersect([Genre (Primary)],[Days To Release],AllPrevious([Measurement Date])))
```

But, it doesn't seem to generate the correct value.  I noticed this when generated a chart and used the P90 function. I then dumped the out to Excel to check it in another tool and Excel match the value generated in the SpotFire chart.

So, there has to be something wrong with my calculated column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

The SpotFire code was correct, it just wasn't taking into consideration one of the dimensions that was present in the Filters that the associated Chart that I was comparing to and couldn't get the numbers to match.

BTW: Here is how I ended up troubleshooting it.

I created a few different statistics to see if I could narrow down what was happening.

First I used the max function:

```
Max([value]) OVER (Intersect([Genre (Primary)],[Days To Release],AllPrevious([Measurement Date])))
```

Then, I used a COUNT function:

```
Count([value]) OVER (Intersect([Genre (Primary)],[Days To Release],AllPrevious([Measurement Date])))
```

It was then that I realized that the count between to the numbers weren't the same and that I was missing a filter.

Here is the correct one:

```
P90([value]) OVER (Intersect([Genre (Primary)],[Days To Release],[Wide Release],AllPrevious([Measurement Date])))
```

BTW: I added the AllPrevious function to the Intersect so that I would only consider entries that occurred before what I was measuring.

Also, here is a picture of what I needed to accomplish:
[image: Trend Value against 90th and 75th %ile]

Jason